How to nail the butt joint at the corner of two perpendicular shed walls framed with doubled studs at the ends?
How to nail the butt joint of two perpendicular (EDIT: shed) walls framed with 2x4s that have doubled studs at their ends?
Toe-nail through the closer stud only using a 3-1/4 inch nail?
Use 4" nails through the faces of both studs and on into the edges of the perpendicular studs?
Something else?
Here's the top view showing how the end studs are doubled up on the wall.  The wall is built on the (EDIT: shed) floor with top and bottom plates and then raised into position.


Maybe I don't understand the question, but why not face nail one stud, then face-nail the second one on top of the first?

@Cheery   Think OP built both walls with the doubles first then put them up.

Toenail two or three times with your usual framing nails wherever you have access (inside or out).
This situation is common, and that's all it takes. There's never a lot of force pulling those studs apart (except maybe warpage). When you position the studs with respect to each other, leave the leading stud about 1/8" proud. As you drive a toenail home it'll shift to flush. (Use the top portion of the hammer head's face to punch the angled nail flush or slightly below. Nails not fully set don't hold as well and can cause problems with your sheathing.)
Be precise about this. It's one of the most common causes of drywall bulges and screw pops. If the studs don't come out flush, whack them into position. You can use a toenail in either direction to help shift the studs.

FYI, the inner stud in the wall at the top of your diagram should've been installed perpendicular to the end stud and tight to the other wall so it acts as backing for wall sheathing at the inside corner. That would've also eliminated this problem.

Thanks. I've edited to add that it's shed, so the drywall issues go away, but is the nailing you suggested adequate for shear?  Anything different when it's an outbuilding?

The nailing as suggested is adequate because you will also adding sheathing to the outside, which will tie the corned together.

There's no shear concern in any residential situation.
